# HttpSendRequestA is false and return 0

Tags: c++, windows, wininet

Hi i am trying to download something using WinInet with a costum user agent the issue is that i fails at HttpSendRequestA the error it return is 0
i dont know what this error means i have tried looking it up but nothing comes up
i get the error using `std::to_string(GetLastError());`
Here is the code bolow

```
std::string GetUrlData(const std::string& resource, const std::string& host)
{
    std::string output = "";
    output.clear();

    HINTERNET hIntSession = InternetOpenA("token", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (!hIntSession) {
        return "ERROR: Session Cannot Start";
    }

    HINTERNET hHttpSession = InternetConnectA(hIntSession, host.c_str(), 80, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);
    if (!hHttpSession) {
        InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
        return "ERROR: Cannot Connect To Internet";
    }

    HINTERNET hHttpRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hHttpSession, "GET", resource.c_str(), 0, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    if (!hHttpRequest) {
        InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
        InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
        return "ERROR: Http Request Failed";
    }

   // const char* szHeaders = "User-Agent: Mozzila\r\n";
    if (!HttpSendRequestA(hHttpRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
        InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
        InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
        return "ERROR: Http Request Failed 2";

    }

    char szBuffer[1024];
    DWORD dwRead = 0;

    do {
        if (!InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwRead)) {
            InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
            InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
            InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
            return "ERROR: Cannot Download";
        }

        if (dwRead == 0)
            break;

        output.append(szBuffer, dwRead);
    }
    while (true);
    return output;
}
```

I call this fuction like so std::string 
`data = GetUrlData("http://example.com/", "http://example.com/");`

Comment: What's the string returned from the function? `InternetConnectA` requires a host and a port, not a URL, so I suspect that could be the failing one.

Comment: ERROR: Http Request Failed 2 is string returned it is also pointed at port 80 witch is http

Comment: I suspect you are invoking `GetLastError` long after other operations have completed.  Hence, the error result is cleared. Call GetLastError immediately after the API fails and before you close any of the handles or do a string operation, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `host` parameter should only be the hostname, not the full URL and the resource should only be the resource part on the host.

Like this:

```
std::string data = GetUrlData("/", "example.com");
```

---

A sidenote: You acquire up to three resources that need to be manually released and try to make sure to release them using `InternetCloseHandle()` but it soon becomes verbose and you risk forgetting one eventually. As it happens, if your `GetUrlData()` call succeeds, you don't release *any* of the resources.

Consider wrapping each resource in a `std::unique_ptr` to get it released automatically. Not only does it make it safer, it also makes it easier to read and maintain the code.

Example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
```

```
// custom deleter for the resource
struct internet_deleter {
    void operator()(HINTERNET hi) { InternetCloseHandle(hi); }
};

// the resource's wrapper type
using ihandle = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer_t<HINTERNET>, internet_deleter>;

// functions for acquiring resources
auto RAII_InternetOpen() {
    ihandle rv(InternetOpenA("token", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0));

    if (rv) return rv;

    throw std::runtime_error("InternetOpenA: " + std::to_string(GetLastError()));
}

auto RAII_InternetConnect(const ihandle& hIntSession, const std::string& host) {
    ihandle rv(
        InternetConnectA(hIntSession.get(), host.c_str(), 80, 0, 0,
                         INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL));
    if (rv) return rv;

    throw std::runtime_error("InternetConnectA: " + std::to_string(GetLastError()));
}

auto RAII_HttpOpenRequest(const ihandle& hHttpSession, const std::string& resource) {
    ihandle rv(
        HttpOpenRequestA(hHttpSession.get(), "GET", resource.c_str(), 0, 0, 0,
                         INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0));
    if (rv) return rv;

    throw std::runtime_error("HttpOpenRequestA: " + std::to_string(GetLastError()));
}
```

With the three functions above, the `GetUrlData()` function becomes simpler and will not leak resources:

```
std::string GetUrlData(const std::string& resource, const std::string& host)
{
    std::string output;

    auto hIntSession = RAII_InternetOpen();
    auto hHttpSession = RAII_InternetConnect(hIntSession, host);
    auto hHttpRequest = RAII_HttpOpenRequest(hHttpSession, resource);

    if (!HttpSendRequestA(hHttpRequest.get(), NULL, 0, NULL, 0))
        throw std::runtime_error("HttpSendRequestA: " + 
                                 std::to_string(GetLastError()));

    char szBuffer[1024];
    DWORD dwRead = 0;

    do {
        if (!InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest.get(), szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwRead))
            throw std::runtime_error("InternetReadFile: " +
                                     std::to_string(GetLastError()));

        if (dwRead == 0)
            break;

        output.append(szBuffer, dwRead);
    } while (true);

    return output;
}

int main() {
    try {
        std::cout << GetUrlData("/", "www.google.com");
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```